# VueJS - passing data from a v-for to a component, and then to another component

Tags: vuejs2

I have a `<header-row>` component which I put at the top of all pages to show a title and a subtitle. This is what I'm wanting to do:

- Show a list of objects from an array, with each item "clickable" to show that item's detail on a separate page (this part is easy)
- Pass a field of the item (like `item.display`) from the list to the next page as a `prop`
- In the new page, use that prop in my `<header-row>` component to show the title for that page.

Seems simple, but I can't get the last two steps working:

## Header Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3 class='text-primary'>{{ title }}</h3>
    <h5 class='text-muted'>{{ subTitle }}</h5>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: [
    'title',
    'subTitle'
  ]
}
</script>
```

## List items:

```
<router-link v-for="item in items" :to="{ name: 'some-page' } myProp="item.name">
    {{ item.display }}
</router-link>
```

## Child Component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <header-row title="myProp"></header-row>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-4'>
          ... stuff here....
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'child-stuff',
  props: [
    'myProp'
  ]
}
</script>
```

## Routing Code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import Dashboard from '@/views/Dashboard'
... more here ....
import AROverview from '@/views/ar/Overview'
import Invoice from '@/views/ar/Invoice'
import APOverview from '@/views/ap/Overview'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'dashboard',
      component: Dashboard
    },
    {
      path: '/receivables/:id',
      name: 'ar',
      component: AROverview
    },
    {
      path: '/invoice/:id',
      name: 'invoice',
      component: Invoice
    },
    ... more ...
    {
      path: '/payables/:id',
      name: 'ap',
      component: APOverview
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Please share your routing code?

Comment: You can get props through routing if you put `props:true` inside that route

Comment: In your `v-for` :to is referenced to which route ?

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh I've stripped out some of the `routes` because I didn't think they apply, so the `v-for` isn't pointing to any route that I've listed above. Although I have a specific use case in mind, my question is somewhat generic I think. How to pass an object through `prop`s. If the `prop` I want is an object, but the route only has the object's `id` -- how does that help?

Comment: You can pass params using routerlink `<router-link :to="{ name: 'som-route', params: { displayname: item.display }}">Display</router-link>`

Comment: And change route for that `{ path: '/somerouter:id', component: SomeComponent, props: (route) => ({ query: route.query.displayname }) }`

Comment: this will pass `query` as a prop to the component

Comment: Ah -- I was just coming to understand why you were both asking about my routes, because I'm trying to pass `props` through a route with just `displayName="item.display"` which is way off. I see what you're getting at now ... changing code...